# Custom widget breaking widget section in admin menu

Tags: widgets, child-theme

I am building a child theme at http://habitat.erniehigh.com for a client. I need to add custom widget that shows recent posts by category. I have built similar widgets elsewhere using basically the same code.

```
    class habitat_posts extends WP_Widget {
  function habitat_posts(){
$widget_ops = array(
'description' => 'Allows you to display a list of recent posts within a particular category.');
$this->WP_Widget('fromcat-widget', 'Recent posts from a Category', $widget_ops);
}
 function form($instance) {
//widgetform in backend
$name = $instance['title'];
$numberposts = $instance['numberposts'];
$catid = $instance['catid'];
$rss = $instance['rss'];
?>
 <?php   }  // end of the instance
 function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['catid'] = $new_instance['catid'];
    $instance['numberposts'] = $new_instance['numberposts'];
    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    $instance['rss'] = $new_instance['rss'];
    return $instance;
    } // end the updated
   function widget( $args, $instance ) {
       extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
         $title = $instance['title'];
         $catid = $instance['catid'];
          $numberposts = $instance['numberposts'];
                  $posts = get_posts('numberposts='.$numberposts.'&category='.$catid);
                   $out = '<ul>';
              foreach($posts as $post) {
              $out .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
                 }
          $out .= '</ul>';
         echo $before_widget;
         echo $before_title.$title.$after_title;
          echo $out;
          echo $after_widget;
          } // end of widget function
      }  // end the whole process ready to register
         register_widget('habitat_posts');
```

When I try to use it on the child theme here everything goes OK except the Widget area in the backend is a jumbled up mess. The new widget is visible and the form fields for creating a new instance are visible and I can drag it to a sidebar but that is all.

Thanks for any suggestions or help 
Ernie

Comment: Is this widget registered in the parent theme or the child? Or is it an plugin? I don't see problems on a quick read.

Comment: I have tried registering it in both, with no joy. The clients want no plugins so everything needs to be built into the child theme. I have tried to implement directly into the parent but again no luck. Maybe it is a theme issue. Thanks janw

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's going wrong with your code... I know that, if you follow the [Codex example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Example), you'll be in the right path.

The following is a merge of your sample code with the Codex's. The `function form()` is missing the fields *numberposts*, *catid* and *rss*, and you have to write this part.
And, when you have it working, you could post the code here as an answer so the community will have a fully working example.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "fromcat_widget" );' ) );

class Fromcat_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'fromcat_widget', // Base ID
            'Recent posts from a Category', // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'Allows you to display a list of recent posts within a particular category.', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        /*
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        */
        $title = $instance['title'];
        $catid = $instance['catid'];
        $numberposts = $instance['numberposts'];
        $posts = get_posts('numberposts='.$numberposts.'&category='.$catid);
        $out = '<ul>';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            $out .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
        }
        $out .= '</ul>';


        echo $before_widget;
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        echo $out;
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();

        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['numberposts'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['numberposts'] );
        $instance['catid'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['catid'] );
        $instance['rss'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['rss'] );

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = $instance['title'];
        $numberposts = $instance['numberposts'];
        $catid = $instance['catid'];
        $rss = $instance['rss'];
        /*
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
        }*/
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

}
```

Comment: Brasofilo Thanks for the input. I had the missing info you mentioned but after reading your comment I replaced it with code I had from a working snippet. That was it. Problem solved. Add the slider and this is a done deal. Thanks again